# dvd drive stopped working in windows 8 64 bit

Tags: windows, hard-drive, memory, 64-bit, dvd

I have a lenovo ideapad y510p windows 8 64 bit for one year.

The optical drive is a matshita dvd ram uj8db by panasonic with the latest driver installed

It suddenly stopped reading cds and dvds.

There has been no mechanical trauma.

I have tried to repair it by driver reinstallation and repeated use windows device manager application.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

You can try cleaning the lens of the DVD drive. Sometimes dust settles on the lens of the laser preventing it form reading the data on the CD/DVD surface.

You can purchase a CD/DVD Lens cleaning kit which are easily available in the market and use it to clean the lens. Instructions for using the kit are provided with it.

Or you can do it manually. All you need is a cotton swab and a little rubbing alcohol. Just wet the cotton swab with the alcohol (don't soak it too much). Power off your laptop and eject the DVD tray using a pin then very gently wipe the lens with the wet swab. After you are done cleaning let it dry for a few minutes then close the tray and power on your laptop. You can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wayZD49aw9c) for more details about the cleaning process.

If cleaning the lens doesn't fix the problem then you might need to take your laptop to the service center to get the faulty DVD drive replaced.

Comment: thanks a lot.trying the fixing instructions in letter and spirit.will let users know once done.thanks again.